# How does proxy_redirect correctly replace the Location URL?

Tags: nginx

I am using the following Nginx reverse proxy configuration.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $Host;
        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header Cache-Control no-store;
        add_header Pragma no-cache;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

The vast majority of the time, it works well. However, problems occur when visiting URLs that have 301 redirects set.

For example, when visiting `http://www.example.com/aaa/`, it should redirect to `http://www.example.com/bbb/`

but it redirects incorrectly to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/bbb/`

After investigating this issue, I found that I should use the `proxy_redirect` parameter instead.

I found a description of `proxy_redirect` on the [Nginx website](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect), but I'm sorry that I didn't fully understand it.

As I understand it, the following usage can be used to solve my problem. The reason for not using a regular expression to get the rest of the URL is that it is automatically appended to the replacement string (am I right?) .

```
proxy_redirect http://$proxy_host/ /;
```

I also have two questions.

1、For non-80 ports, the `$proxy_host` variable should also output the port, something like `127.0.0.1:3000`. But why does the official Nginx example use `http://$proxy_host:8000/`, is this a bug? Or is there something I'm not understanding?

2、Suppose that accessing `http://www.example.com` is incorrectly redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`. In this case, does the above substitution syntax not work, because its substitution condition is at least `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` (the `/` character is missing). How should I solve this problem? Should I use a regular expression to get the full URL for replacement? If so, is the following syntax correct?

```
proxy_redirect ~*http://127.0.0.1:3000(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1;
```

Thank you for your patience in reading, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tested your configuration (without any `proxy_redirect` statements) and it works correctly for me. My only suggestion is to use `curl -I http://www.example.com/aaa/` to find out what your server is responding with (particularly the value of the `Location:` header).

Comment: @RichardSmith It says "`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`". So is it an unconventional issue? Can you answer the question mentioned above? I'm confused about the `proxy_redirect` parameter...

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` is just the first line, what does the line which begins `Location: xxx` contain? That is the value you need to use in the `proxy_redirect` statement in order to change it.

Comment: @RichardSmith It shows `Location: http://127.0.0.1:3000/bbb/`, how should I set proxy_redirect correctly to fix this issue and avoid similar problems again?

Comment: In that case, I do not understand why the configuration in your question is not working. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files and ensure that the `server` block is as it appears in your question. Because, as I stated earlier, that works for me. You should not need to add `proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3000/ /;` - as that is what Nginx does by default.

Comment: @RichardSmith No problems were found after checking the Nginx configuration file, which is identical to the example provided above except for the different domain name. However, after I restarted the Nginx service, everything became normal, which is a strange problem. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @RichardSmith By the way, can you post an answer to the `proxy_redirect` usage question I mentioned? Maybe there are others who have the same confusion.